# The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I saw that there are a lot of questions about the error I received-

> error CS4032: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task <Task <IList  >>'.

This is the code-

```
     public async Task <IList <Alert>> ListOfAlerts (int id)
         {

             IList <Alert> returnList = new List <Alert> ();
             try
             {
                 Users currentUser = await _context.User.Where (x => x.Id == id) .FirstOrDefaultAsync ();

                returnList = await _context.Alert.Include (c => c.Group) .Where (x => x.UsersId == currentUser.Id) .ToListAsync ();

             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
             }

             return returnList;
         }
```

I wrote the code based on the answers and then I was left with the same error.

[image: print screen]

Where am I wrong?
Regards

Comment: Which line throws the error? From what you posted - that's all valid.

Comment: @gunr2171 - the line is--                returnList = await _context.Alert.Include (c => c.Group) .Where (x => x.UsersId == currentUser.Id) .ToListAsync ();

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is the **exact** code and the **actual** code that produces that error? I ask because that method is already `async`, so you should not get that compiler error from this method.

Comment: @R-S I don't believe that the code you posted can produce such an error. As Lasse said, are you _really sure_ the code you posted is producing the error you say? The posted code includes the keyword `async` in the method signature - which if it was missing would cause the error. It would help to create a [mre].

Comment: I often see this problem occurring when someone attempts to use `await` inside a *lambda* inside an `async` method without making the lambda `async` also - but that's not currently evident in the code posted.

Comment: As a non related tip: `FirstOrDefaultAsync` will return `null` if no `Users` is found for the provided id. this will then result in an exception when you try to enumerate the alerts. If you know for certain that a `Users` with that id exists then you could use `FirstAsync` but usually this is not guaranteed and it's good to handle the `null` case. That said I agree this doesn't seem like the problematic code.

Comment: I edited the post and attached a print screen.
The code itself works, but when I do debugging it appears

Comment: Does this error only occur when you are Quick Watching the entire line (and I'm not sure why you're evaluating the whole line), or when running the code normally?

Comment: @gunr2171 it only appears when I do quick watching

Comment: Something funky is going on here, most likely this is the debugger showing this as an error because it doesn't correctly handle an async expression. The fact that you're *debugging* this code means that it compiles just fine, but that error message is a compiler error. Likely there are two compilation steps here, and the second one is the debugger. Basically, you cannot create a quickwatch with `await` in it.

Comment: The error you're seeing there is only valid in the context of the QuickWatch window, may be even the Immediate window too. Where the code is attempting to run in a completey different context. Do you get the error when running the program normally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an `await`ed expression in your (Quick)Watch Window; those inspectors don't support async code.

If you want to inspect your query's results, either:

- Advance the current instruction one line by pressing F10, then inspect `returnList`
- Inspect the result of everything *after* `await` (without the variable assignment as well) and append a `.Result`, so:

  - `_context.Alert.Include(c => c.Group).Where(x => x.UsersId == currentUser.Id).ToListAsync().Result;` (do note that this can cause other problems, especially with frozen threads or within synchronizationcontexed code, AFAIK, essentially deadlocking your debugger)
  - Alternatively, inspect the non-async variant: `_context.Alert.Include(c => c.Group).Where(x => x.UsersId == currentUser.Id).ToList()`

Comment: In addition, you don't need to QuickWatch the entire line, which includes the variable assignment.